# Rails get or post route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm not sure about using a Get or Post route in this scenario.

So Get is used to fetch a resource and Post is to create a resource. But what if you are actually just going into a model database and searching.

For example, what if you are searching for a User by just their phone number input. Would you use a Get or Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, you're looking up a record, which is a GET request. I can understand why you're confused, since you're thinking about POST as passing in a set a parameters via a form.

Ordinarily, you use a POST action when you're creating or updating a record (although for the latter I'd use a PUT or a PATCH.) I don't believe you're saving the phone number input as a new record. You can just have this be a GET request with the phone number passed as a parameter. In the controller action, you can pick up the parameter and pass it to your model in order to do your lookup.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you would want to use `GET` requests for querying resource/resources. `POST` for creating resource. `PUT` for updating the complete resource. `PATCH` for partially updating the resource. And finally `DELETE` for destroying a resource.

As your request is for querying resource/resources, its good to go with `GET` request. One other additional benefit of going with `GET` request in this scenario, is that the end user could bookmark the url after the search and if he accesses the bookmarked url later, it still works without an issue . But if you use `POST` and render it instead of a redirect, then if the end user bookmarks the url, then the browser is going to issue a warning when he/she tries to access the bookmarked url later.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attempting to locate a User record, you will want to use a GET request.

Like you said, a GET request returns a resource at a given location.

So you might say to yourself, "I need to get User 11 from the server". So then you want to write a request to the server that say, "Give me the User record stored at "/users/11" -- and if that is a valid route (i.e., if there is such a record), the server says, "Here you go" as a response.

This is in contrast to a POST request.

In a POST request, you might say to yourself, "I need to update the phone number of User 11". So in that case, you will write a POST request with the route something like "users/11/edit" and you will pass additional data to that record.  In that case, so long as User 11 exists, the server will respond with, "OK, I did that."

Answer (score -1):

If you are dealing with search function, and confused whether to use **POST or GET** method in form.

For me, either of the two is **GOOD** to use, it's just a preference of showing searched parameters in **URL** or not, since it will give you the **same** ActiveRecord result.